# ItemsControl refreshes in two stages because there are too many items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, virtualization, itemscontrol

I have a Window with an ItemsControl that places symbols on a map. The symbols are rather complex (each one is composed of several UserControls).

I have a handful of scenarios, and each scenario places a unique set of symbols on the map. There is a drop-down menu that allows the user to switch between scenarios.

If the user switches to Scenario A (which has 22 symbols), the entire map refreshes in one shot.

If the user switches to Scenario B (which has 39 symbols), the map appears to refresh twice. Some parts of the symbols are drawn, then a brief moment later, the remaining parts of the symbols are drawn. In the end, the symbols appear correctly, but the two-stage refresh is very awkward and looks unprofessional. (It would be as if you were trying to place a bunch of cars on a road map, and instead of the cars just appearing, first the bodies of cars appeared, then a moment later, the wheels and mirrors appeared.)

In trying to debug this, I thought about what was different between the two scenarios, and really the only thing I could think of was that the number of symbols were different. (The differences in the particular attributes all seemed pretty random.) So, I ran a test with just the first 22 symbols of Scenario B. The map refreshed in one shot. I upped the number of symbols several times, and the map still updated in one shot. When I reached 38 symbols, however, the map updated in two stages again. Just in case there was something strange about the last two symbols, I tried skipping the first two then grabbing the remaining 37, but the map updated in one shot again. Finally, I tried skipping the first symbol then grabbing the remaining 38. Now it was back to updating the map in two stages.

Bottom line: if the ItemsControl tries to render 38 or more symbols at once, it happens in two stages, otherwise, it happens in one. I'd like the map to refresh in one stage regardless of the number of symbols.

From what I've read about WPF virtualization, I don't believe this behavior qualifies as virtualization because, once the rendering is complete, none of the symbols are hidden or off-screen. My monitor is large enough that there are no active scroll bars.

So, I'm completely mystified by what I'm experiencing here. Any ideas appreciated.

---

**Update**

I tried setting the Visibility to Hidden, then performing the update, then setting the Visibility back to Visible. Makes no difference. The map still refreshed in to stages. (I also tried Collapsed instead of Hidden, still didn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you explaind seems to be really mystic.
Maybe it could be a temporary option for you to set the opacity of all redrawn symbols to 0 and the visibility to collapsed or hidden.

When choosing the scenario the visibility of all elements changes to "visible".
When the last symbol calls the IsVisibleChanged-event you set the opacity of all elements to 1.

I know, it would be a very unprofessional and rudimentary solution but this could be (if this works) a quickfix for your problem until a really (or more) professional solution will be founded.

kind regards
Shounbourgh